# Select a group of Placemarks graphically?

Tags: google-earth

Is it possible to select a group of Placemarks graphically in Google Earth?
Referring to the attached image, I would like to do *lasso* on one of these groups (indicated by the polygon)

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for `ee.FeatureCollection.filterBounds()`.

Comment: I think you can move all the points to a folder and keep them in a group.

Answer (score 0):

Google Earth does not have a tool for multi-selecting features geographically. To do that, you'll probably want to bring the KML into GIS software of some sort (like QGIS), where you can do all sorts of selections, by geography, attribute, distance, etc.